# How to Round Up an Integer Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to round up an integer with Javascript.

I have a JSON that retrieve an amount e.g 7435 but I want to round it up to 7500, so I can use in an simple math function. Any ideas? Cause round, and ceil are working only with decimals.

Comment: divide by 100, round, multiply by 100

Comment: Divide by 100 then round and then multiply by 100. Does anybody teach basic arithmetic anymore?

Comment: Also why should 7435 round **up** to 7500?

Comment: I need it round it to the nearest top hundred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Math.ceil` function

```
Math.ceil(7435/100)*100;
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) and [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-math.ceil) are much preferred.

Comment: Cool @RobG, why?

Comment: ECMA-262 is the normative reference (it's the language specification), but can be a bit turgid. MDN is a public wiki that is well maintained and has input from some very knowledgeable contributors. While it's not perfect, it has some excellent information on compatibility, pollyfills and links to standards. w3schools is a commercial site that has improved greatly, but seems to lack the comprehensive range of contributors and information available at MDN. But that's just my view. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
x = Math.floor((x+99) / 100)*100;
```

or

```
x = Math.ceil(x/100) * 100;
```

or go learn some Math :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Math.ceil( number / 100 ) * 100` should work. If you do Math.ceil(7435/100) it will give you 75 and multiplying by 100 will give you 7500. Ceil does not only work with decimals.

```js
var rounded = Math.ceil( 7435 / 100) * 100;
console.log(rounded);
```